# Use the result of a CTE in a different block in my procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Can I save the returned result of a cte to a value I've declared?
I would like to use the id field of an CTE in a foor loop which occurs in a different block after the CTE inserted some values.

```
CREATE some_procedure()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $$
DECLARE
some_var uuid;
WITH cte AS(
-- do stuff
RETURNING id INTO some_var --I know it's an error, but I need something like id = some_var
)
...
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried something like this but no luck. And I can't reference the CTE once I've used a semicolon after the final insert:

```
as $$
DECLARE
prod_sku uuid;
attr VARCHAR[];
BEGIN
  WITH ins_category AS(
    INSERT INTO product_category(name)
    VALUES(category_name)
    ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id
    ),
  ins_product AS(
    INSERT INTO product(name, product_category) 
    SELECT product_name, ins_category.id FROM ins_category
    RETURNING sku
    ),
  sel_sku AS(
    prod_sku = SELECT ins_product.sku FROM ins_product --SYNTAX ERROR
    RETURNING product_sku
  )
  INSERT INTO product_price(base_price, product_sku)
  SELECT product_base_price, prod_sku;
  RAISE NOTICE 'prod_sku %', prod_sku;
...
```

I've also tried adding the select after the CTE/semicolone, like in the following example. But, it throws an error that ins_product does not exists, since I've already executed with semicolon.

**HOW CAN I GET THE VALUE FROM THE CTE INTO A DIFFERENT BLOCK IN MY PROCEDURE?**

```
...
  ins_product AS(
    INSERT INTO product(name, product_category) 
    SELECT product_name, ins_category.id FROM ins_category
    RETURNING sku
    )
  INSERT INTO product_price(base_price, product_sku) 
  SELECT product_base_price, ins_product.sku FROM ins_product;
  SELECT * FROM ins_product AS test; -- ERROR HERE
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

I need the sku field from the CTE to use it in a loop:

```
...
 sel_sku AS(
    SELECT ins_product.sku FROM ins_product
    )
  INSERT INTO product_price(base_price, product_sku) 
  SELECT product_base_price, ins_product.sku FROM ins_product;
  FOREACH attr SLICE 1 IN ARRAY product_attributes
  LOOP
    WITH ins_attribute_type AS(
        INSERT INTO product_attribute_type(name, product_sku) 
        SELECT attr[1], prod_sku
        ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
      RETURNING id
      )
    INSERT INTO product_attribute_value(value, attr_type)
    SELECT attr[2], ins_attribute_type.id FROM ins_attribute_type;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
```

Comment: Perhaps you want a temporary table.

Comment: So there is no way of extracting a value from inside of a CTE's scope and using it as a global variable in my function's body?

Comment: First things first: `CREATE some_procedure() ... ` is invalid. I also don't see any [*blocks*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) (except the default outer block) in your plpgsql code. Provide actual code and always your version of Postgres. What do you mean with "block"? And I suspect we are talking about a [*function*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html), not a [*procedure*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)? How many rows are returned by your CTE?

Comment: @S.Schenk . . . Yes.  It is called a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

A CTE essentially a procedure or query window scoped table variable. You can name the CTE so that you now have a named table.

If you want value variables, just query the CTE:

var whatever = Select x from CTE where y

** Update per changes to question **
The "returning" line of your CTE indicates the fields that will make up the CTE.  You should be able to query these tables the same as any other temp table, using the name.

Check the code blocks in your procedure.  In order to query the CTE it will need to be in the same "BLOCK" - that is between your BEGIN and your END commands.  After the "BLOCK" is closed the CTE is out of scope and no longer accessible.

** Hopefully final update **

In this statement:

```
sel_sku AS(
prod_sku = SELECT ins_product.sku FROM ins_product --SYNTAX ERROR
RETURNING product_sku
```

remove the "prod_sku =" portion.  sel_sku will then be single column table made up of the product_sku that fit your SELECT query

Comment: the problem is that I have a chain of data modifying CTEs and they have to end in an insert. Where should I use the select?

Comment: If Iremove the 'prod_sku=' part I'd be able to query the CTE right afterwards. But I need to use the result in a for loop which means it's in another block than the CTE (after a semicolon).

Comment: Should be fine as long as it is in the same "BEGIN" "END" block.  If not, immediately after your cte do var whatever = SELECT FROM cte where xyz to get a single field value.  Not sure why you have sel_sku it should be the exact same as ins_product since you only returned the sku field in that cte.